# You cannot specify an AMI Type other than CUSTOM, when specifying an image id in your launch template

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I'm stuck in a loop here- I'm trying to create a launch template for my eks nodes and my launch template looked like this:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "node" {
  image_id                             = var.image_id
  instance_type                        = var.instance_type
  key_name                             = var.key_name
  instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = "terminate"
  name                                 = var.name
  user_data                            = base64encode("node_userdata.tpl")
#   vpc_security_group_ids               = var.security_group_ids

    block_device_mappings {
        device_name = "/dev/sda1"

    ebs {
      volume_size = 20
    }
  }

  iam_instance_profile {
    name = aws_iam_instance_profile.node.name
  }

  monitoring {
    enabled = true
  }
}
```

Here's my node resource block as well:

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "nodes_eks" {

  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.eks.name
  node_group_name = "eks-node-group"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eks_nodes.arn
  subnet_ids      = module.vpc.private_subnets
  # remote_access {
  #   ec2_ssh_key = aws_key_pair.bastion_auth.id

  # }

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 3
    max_size     = 6
    min_size     = 3
  }

  ami_type             = "AL2_x86_64"
  capacity_type        = "ON_DEMAND"

  force_update_version = false
  instance_types       = [var.instance_type]
  labels = {
    role = "nodes-pool-1"
  }

  launch_template {
    id = aws_launch_template.node.id
    version = "$Default"
  }

  # version = var.k8s_version

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.amazon_eks_worker_node_policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.amazon_eks_cni_policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.amazon_ec2_container_registry_read_only,
  ]
}
```

My image ID for my launch template is this amazon linux 2 image "ami-098e42ae54c764c35". When I tried to run that, it gave me this error

```
You cannot specify an AMI Type other than CUSTOM, when specifying an image id in your launch template
```

So I changed it from **var.image_id** (The Amazon Linux 2 image) to **"CUSTOM"** and it's returning this error now:

```
InvalidAMIID.Malformed: The image ID 'CUSTOM' is not valid. The expected format is ami-xxxxxxxx or ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
```

I don't know what the solution is, because when I passed in the ami via a variable it said the value had to be "CUSTOM", so I made it that and now it's saying it has to be the typical AMI id format.

Comment: Can you show how you are passing those variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have both the `ami_type = "AL2_x86_64"` and `launch_configuration`. The message is a bit misleading, but if you look in [1], you will see where `CUSTOM` has to be used:

> If the node group was deployed using a **launch template** with a custom AMI, then this is CUSTOM.

So, you have to change the following line:

```
ami_type = "CUSTOM"
```

Also, the Terraform docs [2] have something to say about fetching the version of the launch template. The final outlook of your `launch_configuration` block should be:

```
  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.node.id
    version = aws_launch_template.node.latest_version
  }
```

---

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/APIReference/API_Nodegroup.html#AmazonEKS-Type-Nodegroup-amiType

[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_node_group#version